# Reading a HDF5 dataset with compound data type containing multiple sets with variable numbers of floats and ints

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm trying to read a HDF5 dataset with a compound data type using the H5Cpp library in C++. The HDF5 file is created by a simulator, so unfortunately I have no control over the structure. Each cell contains multiple sets of variable length floats and one set of variable length ints. The header structure shown by h5dump is:

```
DATASET "SET_NAME" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_VLEN { H5T_IEEE_F64LE} "dProp1";
            H5T_VLEN { H5T_IEEE_F64LE} "dProp2";
            H5T_VLEN { H5T_STD_I32LE} "iProp1";
            H5T_VLEN { H5T_IEEE_F64LE} "dProp3";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 5, 122 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED, H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
}
```

I've tried to create a `CompType` containing `VarLenType`s, but when running an exception is thrown, stating that a member overlaps with another member (which is what I would expect when the only size given anywhere is the size of a struct containing pointers). This is an excerpt what I have so far:

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
typedef struct mytype_t {
    double* dprop1;
    double* dprop2;
    int* iprop1;
    double* dprop3;
} mytype_t;

H5::CompType ctype(sizeof(mytype_t));
auto double_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;
auto int_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT;
auto vdouble_type = H5::VarLenType(&double_type);
auto vint_type = H5::VarLenType(&int_type);
ctype.insertMember("dProp1", HOFFSET(mytype_t, dprop1), vdouble_type);
ctype.insertMember("dProp2", HOFFSET(mytype_t, dprop2), vdouble_type);
ctype.insertMember("vProp1", HOFFSET(mytype_t, iprop1), vint_type);
ctype.insertMember("dProp3", HOFFSET(mytype_t, dprop3), vdouble_type);

std::vector<mytype_t> data_vector;
data_vector.resize(dims[0]*dims[1]);
dataset.read(data_vector.data(), ctype);
```

How can I read a dataset like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HDF5 documentation and examples are quite weak on this issue.

HDF5 requires users to keep a handle (of type **hvl_t**) to the variable length data and refer to that when you're inserting your array as a member to the compound type.

This introduces an overhead of keeping these handles and your vectors, arrays... etc. synchronized with the handles. That is to say, if you're keeping dynamic arrays, whenever you change the number of elements, you need to update the **"len"** field and whenever the array is reallocated you need to set the **"p"** field to the first element of the new array.

This is also usable with **std::vector**s, keeping in mind that you need to keep updating the **p** and **len** whenever you add/remove elements into the vector. There is a nice piece of code that does that at https://github.com/dguest/hdf5-ntuples/blob/master/include/h5container.hh by dguest.

Solution to your case (simplified):

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
typedef struct mytype_t {
    double* dProp;
    hvl_t dPropHandle;
    int* iProp;
    hvl_t iPropHandle;
} mytype_t;

H5::CompType ctype(sizeof(mytype_t));
auto double_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;
auto int_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT;
auto vdouble_type = H5::VarLenType(&double_type);
auto vint_type = H5::VarLenType(&int_type);

// use handles instead of array pointers
ctype.insertMember("dProp", HOFFSET(mytype_t, dPropHandle), vdouble_type);
ctype.insertMember("iProp", HOFFSET(mytype_t, iPropHandle), vint_type);

std::vector<mytype_t> data_vector;
data_vector.resize(dims[0]*dims[1]);
dataset.read(data_vector.data(), ctype);

// update array pointers accordingly
for(mytype_t &m : data_vector)
{
    m.dProp = dPropHandle.p;
    m.iProp = iPropHandle.p;
}
```

Using vectors:

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
typedef struct mytype_t {
    std::vector<double> dProp;
    hvl_t dPropHandle;
    std::vector<int> iProp;
    hvl_t iPropHandle;
} mytype_t;

H5::CompType ctype(sizeof(mytype_t));
auto double_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;
auto int_type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT;
auto vdouble_type = H5::VarLenType(&double_type);
auto vint_type = H5::VarLenType(&int_type);

// use handles instead of array pointers
ctype.insertMember("dProp", HOFFSET(mytype_t, dPropHandle), vdouble_type);
ctype.insertMember("iProp", HOFFSET(mytype_t, iPropHandle), vint_type);

std::vector<mytype_t> data_vector;
data_vector.resize(dims[0]*dims[1]);
dataset.read(data_vector.data(), ctype);

// update vectors accordingly
for(mytype_t &m : data_vector)
{
    m.dProp.assign(static_cast<double*>(m.dPropHandle.p),
    static_cast<double*>(m.dPropHandle.p) + m.dPropHandle.len);

    m.iProp.assign(static_cast<int*>(m.iPropHandle.p),
    static_cast<int*>(m.iPropHandle.p) + m.iPropHandle.len);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This, at least the variant using vectors, seems to work perfectly for my case.

Comment: I've got a similar compound structure, with an array as the member, but the question is how can I write to the HDF5 file, could you help? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had to deal with HDF5 or even C++ since 2016. If you have any say in it, I would migrate away from HDF5 as a serialization format. 

For example, protobuf is much nicer and has support in many other languages.