# Save Struct with Armadillo Vec to hdf5 file

Tags: c++, hdf5, armadillo

I am trying to save a struct that contains a few arma::vec and I'm not sure on how to write those to the hdf5 file.

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <armadillo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC  //allows the use of GCC compiled armadillo with ICC compiler

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

struct info_struct{
    double frequency_MHz;
    vec beam_centres_deg;
    vec beam_crossover_deg;
    double task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    double WRF_Hz;
    double bandwidth_kHz;
    double beam_spacing_dB;
    int direct_wave_range_bin;
    double fs;
    vec rx_rng_twoway_vec_km;
    string date;
};

int main(void)
{
    info_struct header;

    header.frequency_MHz=7;
    header.beam_centres_deg=8*ones<vec>(10);
    header.beam_crossover_deg=9*ones<vec>(10);
    header.task_centre_azimuth_deg=10;
    header.WRF_Hz = 11;
    header.bandwidth_kHz=12;
    header.beam_spacing_dB=13;
    header.direct_wave_range_bin=14;
    header.fs=15e3;
    header.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km=16*ones<vec>(10);
    header.date="14-Oct-2020 17:02:30";

    // the array of each length of multidimentional data.
    hsize_t dim_header[1];

    dim_header[0] = sizeof(header) / sizeof(info_struct);

    // the length of dim
    int rank_header = sizeof(dim_header) / sizeof(hsize_t);

    // defining the datatype to pass HDF55
    H5::CompType h5_header(sizeof(info_struct));
    h5_header.insertMember("frequency_MHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, frequency_MHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_centres_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_centres_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_crossover_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_crossover_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("task_centre_azimuth_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, task_centre_azimuth_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("WRF_Hz", HOFFSET(info_struct, WRF_Hz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("bandwidth_kHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, bandwidth_kHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_spacing_dB", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_spacing_dB), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("direct_wave_range_bin", HOFFSET(info_struct, direct_wave_range_bin), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    h5_header.insertMember("fs", HOFFSET(info_struct, fs), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("rx_rng_twoway_vec_km", HOFFSET(info_struct, rx_rng_twoway_vec_km), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("date", HOFFSET(info_struct, date), H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE));
    
    // preparation of a dataset and a file.
    H5::DataSpace space_header(rank_header, dim_header);
    H5::H5File *file = new H5::H5File("data_test.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    H5::DataSet *dataset_header = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("MOTHR_header", h5_header, space_header));
    // Write
    dataset_header->write(&header, h5_header);
    
    delete dataset_header;
    delete file;
    return 0;
}
```

if I comment out everything to do with the vectors, it writes to the file just fine but when I leave them uncommented I get this warning when compiling:

```
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:226,
                 from /usr/include/armadillo:62,
                 from save_data.cpp:2:
save_data.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
save_data.cpp:65:53: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("frequency_MHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, frequency_MHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:65:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("frequency_MHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, frequency_MHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                             ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:67:56: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_centres_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_centres_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:67:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_centres_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_centres_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                                ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:68:58: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_crossover_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_crossover_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:68:50: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_crossover_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_crossover_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                                  ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:70:63: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("task_centre_azimuth_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, task_centre_azimuth_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:70:55: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("task_centre_azimuth_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct, task_centre_azimuth_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                                       ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:71:46: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("WRF_Hz", HOFFSET(info_struct, WRF_Hz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:71:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("WRF_Hz", HOFFSET(info_struct, WRF_Hz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                      ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:72:53: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("bandwidth_kHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, bandwidth_kHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:72:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("bandwidth_kHz", HOFFSET(info_struct, bandwidth_kHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                             ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:73:55: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_spacing_dB", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_spacing_dB), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:73:47: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("beam_spacing_dB", HOFFSET(info_struct, beam_spacing_dB), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                               ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:74:61: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("direct_wave_range_bin", HOFFSET(info_struct, direct_wave_range_bin), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
save_data.cpp:74:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("direct_wave_range_bin", HOFFSET(info_struct, direct_wave_range_bin), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
                                                     ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:75:42: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("fs", HOFFSET(info_struct, fs), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
save_data.cpp:75:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("fs", HOFFSET(info_struct, fs), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
                                  ^~~~~~~
save_data.cpp:79:44: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘info_struct’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     h5_header.insertMember("date", HOFFSET(info_struct, date), H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE));
save_data.cpp:79:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOFFSET’
     h5_header.insertMember("date", HOFFSET(info_struct, date), H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE));
```

And the function seems to run fine but when i try `h5dump` on the generated file I get:

```
HDF5 "data_test.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "MOTHR_header" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "frequency_MHz";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "beam_centres_deg";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "beam_crossover_deg";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "task_centre_azimuth_deg";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "WRF_Hz";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "bandwidth_kHz";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "beam_spacing_dB";
         H5T_STD_I32LE "direct_wave_range_bin";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "fs";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "rx_rng_twoway_vec_km";
         H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         } "date";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): {
            7,
            4.94066e-323,
            4.94066e-323,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15000,
            4.94066e-323,
            "14-Oct-2020 17:02:30"
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

I'm very new to hdf5 so I am completely lost on how to save these vectors and any help would be greatly appreciated. I also have another struct with arma:cx_mat. I know that when reading them I had to read them separately then combine them, so is it safe to assume I'll have to do the same for writing them?

UPDATE:

After reading some more about compound datatypes I made modifications to my code:

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <armadillo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC  //allows the use of GCC compiled armadillo with ICC compiler

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

typedef std::vector<double> stdvec;

struct info_struct{
    double frequency_MHz;
    vec beam_centres_deg;
    stdvec beam_centres_deg_c;
    vec beam_crossover_deg;
    stdvec beam_crossover_deg_c;
    double task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    double WRF_Hz;
    double bandwidth_kHz;
    double beam_spacing_dB;
    int direct_wave_range_bin;
    double fs;
    vec rx_rng_twoway_vec_km;
    stdvec rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_c;
    string date;
};

struct info_struct_hdf5{
    double frequency_MHz;
    double* beam_centres_deg;
    hvl_t beam_centres_deg_handle;
    double* beam_crossover_deg;
    hvl_t beam_crossover_deg_handle;
    double task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    double WRF_Hz;
    double bandwidth_kHz;
    double beam_spacing_dB;
    int direct_wave_range_bin;
    double fs;
    double* rx_rng_twoway_vec_km;
    hvl_t rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle;
    string date;
};



int main(void)
{
    info_struct header;
    info_struct_hdf5 header_hdf5;

    header.frequency_MHz=7;
    header.beam_centres_deg=8*ones<vec>(10);
    header.beam_crossover_deg=9*ones<vec>(10);
    header.task_centre_azimuth_deg=10;
    header.WRF_Hz = 11;
    header.bandwidth_kHz=12;
    header.beam_spacing_dB=13;
    header.direct_wave_range_bin=14;
    header.fs=15e3;
    header.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km=16*ones<vec>(10);
    header.date="14-Oct-2020 17:02:30";

    header_hdf5.frequency_MHz=header.frequency_MHz;
    header_hdf5.beam_centres_deg=header.beam_centres_deg.memptr();
    //header_hdf5.beam_crossover_deg=eader.beam_crossover_deg;
    header_hdf5.task_centre_azimuth_deg=header.task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    header_hdf5.WRF_Hz = header.WRF_Hz;
    header_hdf5.bandwidth_kHz=header.bandwidth_kHz;
    header_hdf5.beam_spacing_dB=header.beam_spacing_dB;
    header_hdf5.direct_wave_range_bin=header.direct_wave_range_bin;
    header_hdf5.fs=header.fs;
    //header_hdf5.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km=header.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km;
    header_hdf5.date=header.date;

    // the array of each length of multidimentional data.
    hsize_t dim_header[1];
    dim_header[0] = sizeof(header_hdf5) / sizeof(info_struct_hdf5);
    // the length of dim
    int rank_header = sizeof(dim_header) / sizeof(hsize_t);

    // defining the datatype to pass HDF55
    H5::CompType h5_header(sizeof(info_struct_hdf5));    
    h5_header.insertMember("frequency_MHz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, frequency_MHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_centres_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_centres_deg_handle), H5::VarLenType(H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE));
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_crossover_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_crossover_deg_handle), H5::VarLenType(H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE));
    h5_header.insertMember("task_centre_azimuth_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, task_centre_azimuth_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("WRF_Hz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, WRF_Hz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("bandwidth_kHz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, bandwidth_kHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_spacing_dB", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_spacing_dB), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("direct_wave_range_bin", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, direct_wave_range_bin), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    h5_header.insertMember("fs", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, fs), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("rx_rng_twoway_vec_km", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle), H5::VarLenType(H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE));
    h5_header.insertMember("date", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, date), H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE));
    
    // preparation of a dataset and a file.
    H5::DataSpace space_header(rank_header, dim_header);
    H5::H5File *file = new H5::H5File("data_test.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    H5::DataSet *dataset_header = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("MOTHR_header", h5_header, space_header));
    // Write
    dataset_header->write(&header_hdf5, h5_header);
    
    delete dataset_header;
    delete file;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with now warnings or error so I thought it was at least a step in the right direction but when I run the code I get:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.4) thread 140528006936384:
  #000: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 336 in H5Dwrite(): can't write data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #001: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 828 in H5D__write(): can't write data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #002: ../../../src/H5Dcontig.c line 633 in H5D__contig_write(): contiguous write failed
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #003: ../../../src/H5Dscatgath.c line 704 in H5D__scatgath_write(): datatype conversion failed
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't convert datatypes
  #004: ../../../src/H5T.c line 5025 in H5T_convert(): datatype conversion failed
    major: Datatype
    minor: Can't convert datatypes
  #005: ../../../src/H5Tconv.c line 2512 in H5T__conv_struct_opt(): unable to convert compound datatype member
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #006: ../../../src/H5T.c line 5025 in H5T_convert(): datatype conversion failed
    major: Datatype
    minor: Can't convert datatypes
  #007: ../../../src/H5Tconv.c line 3272 in H5T__conv_vlen(): can't write VL data
    major: Datatype
    minor: Write failed
  #008: ../../../src/H5Tvlen.c line 913 in H5T_vlen_disk_write(): Unable to write VL information
    major: Datatype
    minor: Write failed
  #009: ../../../src/H5HG.c line 543 in H5HG_insert(): unable to allocate a global heap collection
    major: Heap
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #010: ../../../src/H5HG.c line 163 in H5HG__create(): memory allocation failed
    major: Resource unavailable
    minor: No space available for allocation
  #011: ../../../src/H5FL.c line 922 in H5FL_blk_malloc(): memory allocation failed for chunk
    major: Resource unavailable
    minor: No space available for allocation
  #012: ../../../src/H5FL.c line 250 in H5FL_malloc(): memory allocation failed for chunk
    major: Resource unavailable
    minor: No space available for allocation
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'H5::DataSetIException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: thats only a fragment of the error/warning. Please include the complete compiler message in the question

Comment: The problem is most likely due to the fact that you are telling the HDF5 library that armadillo vectors are "just a double" (the last argument of `insertMember`). You probably need to define a new compound datatype for an armadillo vector first. Only after that, you can define the compound datatype of your `info_struct`, since you need to specify the corresponding compound datatype of an armadillo vector as the "HDF5 type" passed as the last argument to `insertMember` for you `vec` members.

Comment: @darcamo I took a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477590/reading-a-hdf5-dataset-with-compound-data-type-containing-multiple-sets-with-var) and tried to work back from that (its about reading not writing) and it compiles with now issue now but when I run it get `memory allocation error` I will update my original post with the new code and errors

Comment: This can get tricky, because HDF5 is basically a C library. One workaround is to create a different struct, with simpler types (using C arrays to store the original armadillo vectors) and use this struct instead of the original one to save/load to/from HDF5.

Comment: @darcamo so that's what I'm trying. I create a replica struct with a `double *` instead of `arma::vec`. `malloc()` for the size of the `vec` and then `memcpy()` and that seems to work but when I try to save it, the way mentioned in the previous comment it compiles and runs with no warnings or errors but when I use h5dump to look at the file, that entry is blank. I think I'm back to an issue with `insertmember()` but I'm extremely new to HDF5 so I'm not sure where to go next...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

First, 2 structs that are very similar:

```
struct info_struct{
    double frequency_MHz;
    vec beam_centres_deg;
    vec beam_crossover_deg;
    double task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    double WRF_Hz;
    double bandwidth_kHz;
    double beam_spacing_dB;
    int direct_wave_range_bin;
    double fs;
    vec rx_rng_twoway_vec_km;
    string date;
};

struct info_struct_hdf5{
    double frequency_MHz;
    hvl_t beam_centres_deg_handle;
    hvl_t beam_crossover_deg_handle;
    double task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    double WRF_Hz;
    double bandwidth_kHz;
    double beam_spacing_dB;
    int direct_wave_range_bin;
    double fs;
    hvl_t rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle;
    string date;
};
```

Next transfer the data from the original struct to this new buffer struct:

```
    header_hdf5.frequency_MHz=header.frequency_MHz;
    header_hdf5.beam_centres_deg_handle.p=header.beam_centres_deg.memptr();
    header_hdf5.beam_centres_deg_handle.len = header.beam_centres_deg.n_elem;
    header_hdf5.beam_crossover_deg_handle.p=header.beam_crossover_deg.memptr();
    header_hdf5.beam_crossover_deg_handle.len = header.beam_crossover_deg.n_elem;
    header_hdf5.task_centre_azimuth_deg=header.task_centre_azimuth_deg;
    header_hdf5.WRF_Hz = header.WRF_Hz;
    header_hdf5.bandwidth_kHz=header.bandwidth_kHz;
    header_hdf5.beam_spacing_dB=header.beam_spacing_dB;
    header_hdf5.direct_wave_range_bin=header.direct_wave_range_bin;
    header_hdf5.fs=header.fs;
    header_hdf5.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle.p=header.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km.memptr();
    header_hdf5.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle.len = header.rx_rng_twoway_vec_km.n_elem;
    header_hdf5.date=header.date;
```

Create a new type:

```
hid_t vlen_tid = H5Tvlen_create(H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
```

Then insert the members using the buffer:

```
h5_header.insertMember("frequency_MHz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, frequency_MHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_centres_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_centres_deg_handle), vlen_tid);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_crossover_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_crossover_deg_handle), vlen_tid);
    h5_header.insertMember("task_centre_azimuth_deg", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, task_centre_azimuth_deg), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("WRF_Hz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, WRF_Hz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("bandwidth_kHz", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, bandwidth_kHz), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("beam_spacing_dB", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, beam_spacing_dB), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("direct_wave_range_bin", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, direct_wave_range_bin), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    h5_header.insertMember("fs", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, fs), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    h5_header.insertMember("rx_rng_twoway_vec_km", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, rx_rng_twoway_vec_km_handle), vlen_tid);
    h5_header.insertMember("date", HOFFSET(info_struct_hdf5, date), H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE));
```

And it works beautifully for me!